# Intermittent "binding" parameter contains a character that is not allowed

Tags: canvas

I have many orgs with my app in it, and my app has a Canvas component, and intermittently for the last couple days this one org has been showing the following error:

> The value of the "binding" parameter contains a character that is not
>   allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the
>   character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and
>   resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer
>   Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well
>   as any other related information.

Then it fixes itself. This shows up both on pages that pass dynamic parameter data to the Canvas app as well as on a page that only passes a hardcoded parameter of page_type, which works in all the other apps.

Anybody know anything about what's going on here?

Comment: Oh, I should note that I don't have anything set up anywhere with the word 'binding' - no parameters, no custom objects, no custom fields. I haven't found anything named binding.

Answer (score 1):

We found this known issue in Winter 16: [Canvas App Doesn't Load in Internet Explorer Due to Parameter Length](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jZ8iAAE)

The circumstance of the error is similar; there's content in the parameters to [canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm) that seems like it could cause a too-long URL, but the error message quoted in the question is coming from `foo.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpPost/services/oauth2/authorize`, not a URL that seems to be cut off by an IE limitation. (Especially as we're seeing this in non-IE browsers.)